# How to return multiple function in conditional statement?

Tags: reactjs, function, if-statement

I have 3 functions and i have one common button to call a function(Its a toggle button). So what i tried is im using if to call function based on count value. For example if count value is 0 (count ==0 ) then return (function). If count is 1 (count==1) then return ( function1() && function2 ) so in second if im  trying to call two function and on click of button, both function should be called. but by using & operator im not able to call two functions. How to call two functions in return statement??

here is source code.

Functions

```
 const handleLeft = () => {
    scene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true, false, true);
    var camera1 = scene.getCameraByID("default camera");
    camera1.upperBetaLimit = BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(90);
    camera1.lowerBetaLimit = BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(90);
    camera1.beta = -2.0;
    camera1.alpha = -2.0;
    camera1.radius = 0.25;
    camera1.detachControl(canvas, true)
}

const handleRight = () => {
scene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true, false, true);
var camera2 = scene.getCameraByID("default camera");
camera2.upperBetaLimit = BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(90);
camera2.lowerBetaLimit = BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(90);
camera2.beta = 5.2;
camera2.alpha = 5.2;
camera2.radius = 0.25;
camera2.detachControl(canvas, true)
}

  const handleCenter = () => {
    scene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true, false, true);
    var camera3 = scene.getCameraByID("default camera");
     camera3.upperBetaLimit = BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(90)
    camera3.lowerBetaLimit = BABYLON.Tools.ToRadians(90)
    camera3.beta = 4.4;
    camera3.alpha = 4.4;
    camera3.radius = 0.25;
    camera3.detachControl(canvas, true)
  }
```

If condition

```
 const handleCount = () => {
  if (preview_images_count === 0)
  {
  return handleCenter()
  }
  
  if (preview_images_count === 1)
  {
  return handleRight() && handleCenter()
  } 
  
  if (preview_images_count === 2)
  {
  return  handleLeft() && handleRight() && handleCenter()
  }
 }
```

This  button where im calling handleCount function which is calling other functions based on count value.

```
        <button type="button" class="btn">
          <img src={circle_regular}
            alt=""
            onClick={handleCount}
            style={myCircleStyle} />
        </button>
```

Comment: Do you just want to call them in succession? If so, there is no need to have '&&'. Just call them one after the other. The && operator will just return true/false

Comment: Hi Marios, Thanks for response. I tried this way but it didnt work.                                 if (preview_images_count === 2)
  {
  return handleLeft(), handleRight(), handleCenter()
  }

Comment: What im trying to achive here is, onClick event i call a function which is having count values and based on count value im trying to call multiple functions.

Comment: Yeah, dont return them, just call them like if (preview_images_count === 2){ handleLeft(); handleRight(); handleCenter() }

Comment: i tried but didnt work, Button still not able to call functions based on count value.    const handleCount = () => {
  if (preview_images_count === 0)
  { 
    handleCenter(); 
  } 
  if(preview_images_count === 1)
  {
     handleRight(); handleCenter();
     }
  
  if (preview_images_count === 2)
    { 
      handleLeft(); handleRight(); handleCenter();
     } 
 }

Comment: you have to increment the preview_images_count somewhere though. Are you doing it ?

Comment: No Marios, Im getting preview_images_count value from api and the values will be just 0,1,2. so im using condition like preview_image_count == 0 like that. So when count value matched with api count value, then condition satisfied should call specific function. If count value is 2 means im calling three functions and function should get executed. handleLeft, handleRight, handleCenter are three functions here which im trying to call.